# Can't show picture with plt.imshow

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, mat

I want to plot a series of images that are stored in the numpy array x_val but plt.imshow(val[1]) does not work. On the other hand with opencv it works fine:

```
    cv2.imshow('image', x_val[1])
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

From what I've read so far I think the problem is that the image is currently in BGR and has to be transformed to RGB (correct me if I'm wrong). So I tried the following:

```
img = cv2.imshow('image', x_val[1])
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

But I got this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Maximal\Documents\Python\PyCharm\TrafficSignClassification\model\trafficSignsClassification.py", line 156, in evaluateTestData
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

One other thing I tried was this approach:

```
        img = np.array(x_val[1], dtype=np.uint8)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.imshow(img)
```

This did not give me an error but the picture was just black. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
What I have done with the pictures in the first place was the following:

```
def preprocessData(self, x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val):
    # --- normalize images ---
    def normalize(img):
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Grayscale image
        img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)                  # Optimize Lightning
        img = img / 255.0                            # Normalize px values between 0 and 1
        return img

    for x in range(len(x_train)):
        x_train[x] = normalize(x_train[x])

    for x in range(len(x_val)):
        x_val[x] = normalize(x_val[x])

    # --- transform the data to be accepted by the model ---
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    y_val = np.array(y_val)
    x_train = np.array(x_train)
    x_val = np.array(x_val)
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1)
    x_val = x_val.reshape(x_val.shape[0], x_val.shape[1], x_val.shape[2], 1)
    print("preprocessing data done.")
    return x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val
```

I use the pictures in a CNN in TF2 so I had to transform them respectively.
I can plot the pictures with plt.imshow() before the transformation without problems. But after this function only cv2.imshow() works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It would help if you had minimum working code that could be copy and pasted and produce the error. I am curious what cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) is?

Comment: what do you get for `x_val[1].shape` ?

Comment: You use `img = cv2.imshow('image', x_val[1])` and then try to use `plt.imshow(img)`? Note that `cv2.imshow()` doesn't have a return value, so `img` would be `None`.

Comment: @tom10 The shape of one picture is (32, 32, 1)

Comment: An image with colors would have a dimension that equaled 3 or 4 for the different colors, eg, (32, 32, 3). This is at least part of your problem. Your current answer is inconsistent with this and the error message, so something else probably changed in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I had to multiply the values by 255 in order to get a proper image. Before all values were between 0 and 1 and this lead to a black image.

```
        img = np.array(x_val[i]*255, dtype=np.uint8)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.imshow(img)
```